# Want to fill data from array of string to datatable in c#

Tags: c#

```
public void DecryptFile(string filePath, string CompanyName)
{
                
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var gzStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                gzStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                byte[] outputBytes = outputStream.ToArray();
                // DeserailizeByteArrayToDatatable(outputBytes, CompanyName);
                string FileContents = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outputBytes);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string[] arrayList = FileContents.Split("\n");
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```

I have decrypted contents of file and now I want to fill the data to `DataTable`. The format of file contents is:

```
serial_number,peak_period_start_time,stop_time
15AA01AF361903PC,1602619200,1602615600
15AA01AF361902QB,1602619200,1602615600
15AA01AF361906YL,1602619200,1602630000
09AA01AF32190YXP,1602619200,1602630000
```

so I want to fil the first line as column in `DataTable` and rest all as rows and aslo additionally I want to change the `start_time` and stop time to correct format

Comment: Any particular reason for using a datatable? I'd probably suggest creating a method to parse the string into a list of objects instead.

Comment: Please check the example for DataTable at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-5.0

Comment: _additionally I want to change the starttime and stop time to correct format_ - don't instead parse both to `DateTime` type and save it as `DATETIME` in the database as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to first create a method that will accept a `DataTable` and an array of columns and will add columns to the `DataTable`.

```
public DataTable AddColumns(DataTable dt, string[] columns)
{
    if (dt == null) dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (string column in columns)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(column.Trim());
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Then, Create a method that will populate data into that `DataTable`:

```
public DataTable PopulateData(DataTable dt, string[] dataLines)
{
    if (dataLines == null || dataLines.Length == 0) return dt;

    foreach (string line in dataLines)
    {
        var splittedLine = line.Split(',');
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < splittedLines.Length; i++)
        {
            row[i] = splittedLines[i].Trim();
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Call the methods above in your `DecryptFile` method, like below:

```
public void DecryptFile(string filePath, string CompanyName)
{
                
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var gzStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                gzStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                byte[] outputBytes = outputStream.ToArray();
                // DeserailizeByteArrayToDatatable(outputBytes, CompanyName);
                string FileContents = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outputBytes);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string[] arrayList = FileContents.Split("\n");
                // Usage
                if (arrayList.Length > 0)
                {
                   var columns = arrayList[0].Split(',');
                   var data = arrayList.AsEnumerable().Skip(1).ToArray(); // skip the first line.
                   dt = PopulateData(AddColumns(dt, columns), data);
                }
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```

**Note:** I see, your file has 4 columns in header row and it is supplying 3 values which is not correct, you must supply equal columns and its values otherwise, you might want to handle the row creation differently.

Answer (score 0):

The general concept I would follow would be to:

1. Read the first row and determine which and how many columns I need to create
2. For each column use `f.Columns.Add()` to add the column to the DataTable.
3. For each row following do `f.Rows.Add()` filling in the data.

Something like:

```
    public void DecryptFile(string filePath, string CompanyName)
    {
        
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (var gzStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    gzStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                    byte[] outputBytes = outputStream.ToArray();
                    //DeserailizeByteArrayToDatatable(outputBytes, CompanyName);
                    string FileContents = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outputBytes);
                    DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
                    string[] arrayList = FileContents.Split('\n');

                    int rowIndex = 0;
                    foreach (string line in arrayList)
                    {
                        // Assuming comma separated columns
                        string[] columns = line.Split(',');
                        int columnIndex = 0;
                        DataRow row = (rowIndex == 0 ? null : newTable.NewRow());
                        foreach (string columnValue in columns)
                        {
                            if (rowIndex == 0)
                            {
                                newTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(columnValue));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                row[columnIndex] = columnValue;
                            }
                        }

                        rowIndex ++;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

(have not tested the code)

Answer (score 0):

You can create data table by using below function. I am not sure what format you want for start time and end time, so I have mentioned it in comments where you can do that.

```
public static DataTable ArrayOfStringToDataTable(string[] stringArray)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        if (stringArray.Length == 0)
        {
            return dataTable;
        }
        var headers = stringArray[0].Split(',');
        foreach (var header in headers)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(header, typeof(string));
        }
        if (stringArray.Length == 1)
        {
            return dataTable;
        }
        for (var i = 1; i < stringArray.Length; i++) {
            var rows = stringArray[i].Split(',');
            var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow[0] = rows[0];
            dataRow[1] = rows[1]; // do required formatting
            dataRow[2] = rows[2]; // do required formatting
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```